# How to find element if I'm looking for text value and there is 2 elements with the same text?

Tags: cypress

I tried to find element (calendar - day of month option) by text `'30'` using:

```
cy.get('td.day').contains('30').should('have.attr', 'data-day', '30.04.2021').click()
```

but instead of click `30.04.2021`, it clicked `30.03.2021`, so I changed code:

```
cy.get('td.day').contains('30').eq(1).should('have.attr', 'data-day', '30.04.2021').click()
```

Unfortunately it didn't help. I see that `'eq'` (or `'last'`) doesn't find values from `get` + `contains` but only from `get`.
How do you resolve such a problem?

Comment: can you share your html DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If your selector is correct this is [the way to select it](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Selector):

```
cy.get('td.day[data-day="30.04.2021"]').click()
```

or simply

```
cy.get('[data-day="30.04.2021"]').click()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. 
Thanks a lot :-)